# Keyboard listener in SwiftUI: 1-by-1 delivery of keys

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, keyboard-events, keylistener

I would like to intercept the keyboard input events in a `TextField` as they come in, i.e. when the user types "Coffee", I want it to trigger 6 events:

1. C
2. o
3. f
4. f
5. e
6. e

Is there a way to do this in *SwiftUI*?

I tried the `onChange` modifier on the `TextField` like this:

```
TextField("key", text: $string)
    .onChange(of: string) { newValue in
        print("\(newValue)")
    }
```

but it sometimes only fires after multiple keys have been pressed when I type really fast, for example, I might get these updates:

1. C
2. Coff
3. Coffe
4. Coffee

Is there a way to get typed keys delivered as an input stream with 1 key at a time?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following to deliver 1 key at a time:

```
    TextField("key", text: $string)
        .onReceive(string.publisher.last()) { val in
            print("val: \(val)")
        }
```

EDIT

".... is there any way to register a backspace key press?...", try the following simple extension:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var string = ""
    @State var prevString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("key", text: $string).border(.red)
            .onReceive(string.publisher.last()) { val in
                if string.count < prevString.count {
                    print("backspace pressed, do something clever here")
                } else {
                    print("val: \(val)")
                }
                prevString = string
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Nice approach! However, it's only triggered when the `onChange` closure is triggered as well, so when multiple value change at once (like `abc`), this only prints the last of these letters (`c`). Also, is there any way to register a backspace key press?

Comment: The code above works perfectly as fast as I can type. I suspect you have some other issue in your app that is causing the issue, but that would be another question, and you would need to supply more code.

Comment: It might work well on a phone, but not on a Mac (or an iPad) with a hardware keyboard. Apparently, iOS handles simultaneous key input differently than macOS (or it's really a hardware vs. software keyboard thing). Another disadvantage of this method is that it always outputs the last letter of the string, even when you hit backspace. So as an observer, when someone types "coffee", you can't distinguish if the user types an "e" or hits backspace next. It would output an "e" in both cases and that's not what I want.

Comment: updated my answer addressing the backspace press.